# Partial Class to a generated class in EF bug?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am used to VB and is kind of new to C# syntax. But from what I read everywhere the syntax seems to be kind of identical for Partial Classes.

I am trying to make a partial class to a generated partial class generated with Entity Framework.

It seems like my class can't reach the other one.

The error:

> 'XmasMVC.CmsSystemPagePart' does not contain a definition for
>   'DefaultLanguageCode' and no extension method 'DefaultLanguageCode'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'XmasMVC.CmsSystemPagePart' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can compile but then I get errors while running. Seems like my class overwrites the generated one.

This is the genereated class from EF.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace XmasMVC
{
    using System;

    public partial class CmsSystemPagePart
    {
        public string DefaultLanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string PagePartName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DefaultLangValue { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my class.

```
namespace XmasMVC
{
    using System;

    public partial class CmsSystemPagePart
    {
        public string GetValue()
        {
            if (this.Value == null)
                return this.DefaultLangValue;
            else return this.Value;
        }

        public string GetLanguageCode()
        {
            if (this.Value == null)
                return this.DefaultLanguageCode;
            else return this.LanguageCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Found this "Warning":

> "The type 'XmasMVC.CmsSystemPagePart' >in 'C:\VSS\Comdigit\Xmas\XmasMVC\App_Code\CmsSystemPagePart.cs' **conflicts with the imported >type** 'XmasMVC.CmsSystemPagePart' in 'C:\VSS\Comdigit\Xmas\XmasMVC\'. Using the type defined >in 'C:\VSS\Comdigit\Xmas\XmasMVC\App_Code\CmsSystemPagePart.cs"

This is how the Objects Browser looks like. Strange for me!

[image: Object Browser]

Comment: Both the EF and your partial classes are in the same assembly, right?

Comment: Can you use extension methods instead partial class?

Comment: Yes: Both are in the same assembly. After making my own Partial I can not reach the generated one. I see now this "Warning" message: "Warning The type 'XmasMVC.CmsSystemPagePart' in 'XmasMVC\App_Code\CmsSystemPagePart.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'XmasMVC.CmsSystemPagePart' in 'XmasMVC\'. Using the type defined in 'XmasMVC\App_Code\CmsSystemPagePart.cs'."

Comment: Rasher: Yes I could. But I would like to be able to do partials to Entity Framework generated classes in the future. This is my "learning" project. ;)

Comment: Updated the question with more info.

Comment: You're using the `App_Code` feature - you have *two* assemblies (with the same name). You'd have exactly the same problem if you'd tried this in VB. So the answer to Stuart's question was actually no.

Comment: Sorry, Did not realize it made a differens. Tried to move the Partial but cannot access the new methods. Where should the self made partial file be placed?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) link here explains that

> In general, ASP.NET creates an assembly for each application directory (such as App_Code) and one for the main directory.

For your case, although the partial classes are in the same project *and* the same namespace they are not being compiled into the same assembly.

Try moving the source files out of App_Code and make sure their `Build action` is `Compiled` in the properties window.